# Azure Key Vault access policies and Managed Identities (ARM templates)

Tags: azure, key, azure-keyvault, azure-application-gateway

Looking for expertise to help.

I have created ARM template, which deploys Azure Application Gateway and Key Vault instances. I want to give **principalID** (user assigned managed identity) of App Gateway in Key Vault to get certificate or secret but it fails with an error:

**"Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'kv-project-dev/add' at line '1' and column '21178' is not valid: The language expression property 'principalId' can't be evaluated.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details."**

**It works fine** if I add **principalID** value of user managed identity in the **parameters.json** file manually (as objectID), however, I am looking how to automate this part and add **principalID** during ARM template deployment automatically in Key Vault access policies.

It seems an issue with this line in **parameters.json** file:

```
"objectId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', variables('appgw-managed-id')).principalId)]"
```

The following resources used to create ARM template:
[New way to reference managed identity in ARM template](https://www.codeisahighway.com/there-is-a-new-way-to-reference-managed-identity-in-arm-template/) and [App Gateway v2 deployment with Key Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/resources/templates/application-gateway-key-vault-create/)

**Parameters.json** file looks for access policies:

```
"kv-servicePrincipalObjects": {
  "value": [
    {
    "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantid]",
    "objectId": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx",
    "permissions": {
        "keys": [],
        "secrets": ["get","list"],
        "certificates": []
    },
    "applicationId": ""
    },
    {
      "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantid]",
      "objectId": "yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy",
      "permissions": {
          "keys": ["all"],
          "secrets": ["all"],
          "certificates": ["all"]
      },
      "applicationId": ""
    },
    {
      "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantid]",
      "objectId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', variables('appgw-managed-id')).principalId)]",
      "permissions": {
          "keys": [],
          "secrets": ["get"],
          "certificates": ["get"]
      },
      "applicationId": ""
    }
  ]
},
```

**Template.json** file to create Key Vault and assign access policies:

```
{
        "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
        "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
        "name": "[variables('kv-name')]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "tags": "[parameters('resource-Tags')]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', variables('vnet-name'))]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', variables('appgw-managed-id'))]"
        ],
         "properties": {
            "enabledForDeployment": "[parameters('kv-enabledForDeployment')]",
            "enabledForTemplateDeployment": "[parameters('kv-enabledForTemplateDeployment')]",
            "enabledForDiskEncryption": "[parameters('kv-enabledForDiskEncryption')]",
            "enableRbacAuthorization": "[parameters('kv-enableRbacAuthorization')]",
            "accessPolicies": [],
            "tenantId": "[parameters('tenant')]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('kv-sku')]",
                "family": "A"
            },
            "enableSoftDelete": "[parameters('kv-enableSoftDelete')]",
            "softDeleteRetentionInDays": "[parameters('kv-softDeleteRetentionInDays')]",
            "enablePurgeProtection": "[parameters('kv-enablePurgeProtection')]",
            "KVvirtualNetworkConfiguration": {
                "KVsubnetResourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', variables('vnet-name'), 'kv-subnet')]"
            },
            "networkAcls": {
                "defaultAction": "Deny",
                "bypass": "AzureServices",
                "virtualNetworkRules": [
                {
                    "id": "[concat(parameters('kv-virtualNetworks'), '/subnets/','kv-subnet')]",
                    "ignoreMissingVnetServiceEndpoint": false
                }
                ],
                "ipRules": "[parameters('kv-ipRules')]"
            }
        }
    },
{
        "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies",
        "name": "[concat(variables('kv-name'), '/add')]",
        "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', variables('kv-name'))]"
            ],
        "properties": {
            "copy": [
            {
                "name": "accessPolicies",
                "count": "[length(parameters('kv-servicePrincipalObjects'))]",
                "input": {
                    "tenantId": "[parameters('kv-servicePrincipalObjects')[copyIndex('accessPolicies')].tenantId]",
                    "objectId": "[parameters('kv-servicePrincipalObjects')[copyIndex('accessPolicies')].objectId]",
                    "permissions": {
                        "keys": "[parameters('kv-servicePrincipalObjects')[copyIndex('accessPolicies')].permissions.keys]",
                        "secrets": "[parameters('kv-servicePrincipalObjects')[copyIndex('accessPolicies')].permissions.secrets]",
                        "certificates": "[parameters('kv-servicePrincipalObjects')[copyIndex('accessPolicies')].permissions.certificates]"
                    },
                    "applicationId": "[parameters('kv-servicePrincipalObjects')[copyIndex('accessPolicies')].applicationId]"
                }
            }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you have a typo here: `variables('appgw-managed-id')).principalId)`, it should be `variables('appgw-managed-id'))).principalId`

Comment: @juunas, you are a star! Thanks for a quick review and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line had a typo in it:

```
"objectId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', variables('appgw-managed-id')).principalId)]"
```

It should be:

```
"objectId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', variables('appgw-managed-id'))).principalId]"
```

Note we moved the closing parenthesis at the end.
The line was trying to get the principalId property from the result of resourceId(), when it needs to get it from the object returned by reference().